# Javax Bluetooth API

Tags: java, bluetooth

I have got the JSR-000082 JavaTM APIs for Bluetooth (Final Release) to develop my bluetooth application. Now the question is, how can i add this API to existing javax package.??
Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: why would you want to add it to javax package? and not just use it in your application as just another library?

Comment: It will facilitate me so that whenever i do "import.javax.*" i got all of that APIs. Using the code for API in my application will make my code even larger. So i dont want this to happen.

Comment: Are you familiar with the concepts of jars and classpath?

Comment: @Salman: If i got this right, you have code for the jsr which is packaged as 'btapi_source\javax\bluetooth' right?

Comment: exactly Shaunak sir. I have code for jsr. You got it rightly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay here are the steps you need to follow.

1. Compile the JSR first. you should now get the .class files.
2. the package intended for each of these class files is javax.bluetooth
3. find the javax jar and extract it. create a folder called 'bluetooth' in side 'javax'   folder and copy all class files.
4. now re bundle it and use it as usual.

Let me know if you need further explanation on these steps.

PS: I am curious, you have tagged this question as java, while the JSR you referring to belongs to J2ME.  you using J2ME right?

Comment: I will definatly let you know. Thank you so much for your help sir.

Answer (score 0):

The reason why you can't figure out how to do this is because you misunderstand how the import system in Java works.

Do you have a jar file containing the API? You simply need to add it to both your compile and runtime classpaths. This can be accomplished in many ways dependending on your build environment, but assuming you're not using a build tool, check out the "-cp " option of `javac` and `java` commands. You can then add the proper import statements in your code.

Comment: I think he is right in asking this question in this case because he is asking about JSRs . If you download this JSR it is packaged as source code and packaged under 'javax' package of its own. So yes it is intended to be merged with existing javax package in this case.